# Unity GetComponent gets the base class -- not the derived

Tags: unity-game-engine

Class B inherits from Class A.

I call: `GetComponent<A>.SomeFunction();`

Class B is on the component, and it overrides `SomeFunction()`. But `SomeFunction()` only runs through the base class.

If I call `GetComponent<B>.SomeFunction()` then it does, indeed, run the
derived class.

Is this the expected behavior in Unity?

Edit:

**Class A**

```
public class Attacker : MonoBehaviour
{
    // The range a unit can attack in, based on where it is currently standing
    public virtual HashSet<Tile> GetAttackRangeTiles() {
        print("base invocation")
        return new HashSet<Tile>();
    }
}
```

**Class B**

```
public class Mage : Attacker
{
    override
    public HashSet<Tile> GetAttackRangeTiles() {
        print("derived invocation");
        return new HashSet<Tile>();
    }
}
```

**Board.cs**

```
public class Board : MonoBehaviour {
    public void ProcessUnitAttackSelect(Unit unit) {
        foreach (Tile tile in unit.GetComponent<Attacker>().GetAttackRangeTiles()) {
            tile.SetState(Tile.State.AttackSelect);
        }
    }
}
```

The above prints "base invocation", not "derived invocation".

Comment: Well yes. You asked for a component that is A. So it ran the A version. You then did it with B version so it ran B

Comment: @BugFinder assuming the method is `virtual` in the base and `override` in the derived, shouldn't a reference to `class A` from a GameObject with a script component of `class B : A` be a validly overridable method even called from "base class of derived class"? Isn't that the whole point of `virtual-override` method relationships?

Comment: Yes, if the method is virtual, the compiler will go down the bottom of the virtual table. You should show the code as their may be something about a generic collection.

Comment: If its virtual why didnt you tell us?

Comment: Could you post a complete code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out -- both class B **and** class A were components on the object. By removing class A (the parent class), B ran as expected. Nasty bug!